# Update values in one array based on another in the same JSON file

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "download": [0, 0, 0, 0],
    "files": [ "file1.txt", "file1.iso", "file2.txt", "file2.iso" ] 
}
```

For each element in `files[]` ending in `.txt` I want to set the corresponding element in `download[]` to `1`. How do I do that in JQ? I googled around but don't really understand JQ syntax.

Answer (score 2):

In this case constructing `download` from scratch would be much easier.

```
.download = (.files | map(if endswith(".txt") then 1 else 0 end))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pdg31rfEbC)</sup>

But the title asks *how to update one array based on another?*, and here is one way of doing it:

```
.download = reduce (.files | path(.[] | select(endswith(".txt")))) as $p (.download; setpath($p; 1))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JV6J_ytsPG)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, actually I figured out the first solution with some trial and error but the second one is super useful!